# Display and Select only Month an Year in Ajax Calendar Extender

Tags: ajax, user-interface, calendar

I want my calendar to display only month and year and as well as select only month from the calendar.

I have used a function which does one part of my requirement, but my main part is not fulfilled by this code, i.e. initially `extender` displays month in grid form but when I select a month it opens the date part of that calender. I want the clicked month to get displayed in the textbox with year for e.g. if I click `jun` the `jun/2013` should get displayed.

I have used this function:

```
function calendarShown(sender, e) {
    sender._switchMode("months", true); 
}
```

This is how I have called it:

```
<AjaxControlToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="txtNextHearingMonth_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
TargetControlID="txtNextHearingMonth" OnClientShown="calendarShown">

</AjaxControlToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Epoch calendar, It provides different options to display the calendar.

[Have a look at this.](http://www.epoch-calendar.com/javascript_calendar/)

You may also use [jquery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Here is a working script

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"    
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" 
href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
     $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
      }
   }); 
});
 </script>
<style>
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
  display: none;
  }
</style>
</head>
```

Date :

Comment: i want only month and year to get displayed and selected,how is it possible through Epoch calender?

Comment: @Anuj Your question's been answered!